# ImportError whilst importing excel file into python script

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas, xlrd

So I tried importing my first excel file into a python document in VIM today and it's not gone well. **Worth noting** is that I unwillingly have 3 versions of Python, v2.7, 3.6 and 3.7 with Python 3.6 being the used version.

I managed to enable python mode on Vim earlier, and that seems to work. And I've managed to install panda but xlrd doesn't seem to work.

I'm trying to import an excel-file with the name: names.xsl into my lab5.py script, but every time I run the python script I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/io/excel.py", line 261, in __init__
    import xlrd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xlrd'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lab5.py", line 2, in <module>
    df = pd.read_excel (r'/home/Lab05/names.xsl')
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 118, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/io/excel.py", line 230, in read_excel
    io = ExcelFile(io, engine=engine)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/io/excel.py", line 263, in __init__
    raise ImportError(err_msg)
ImportError: Install xlrd >= 0.9.0 for Excel support
```

The annoying part is that I already have xlrd installed and it's telling me to install it? Why is this? This is my python script so far:

```
  1 import pandas as pd
  2 df = pd.read_excel (r'/home/Lab05/names.xsl')
  3 print (df)
```

Comment: You may be using Python 3.6, but it sounds as if you have installed it for another Python version. Presumably, you did something like `pip install xlrd`, which could be another pip than you intended. Try `python3.6 -m pip install xlrd` (or however you run Python).

Comment: hampus@hampus-VirtualBox:~$ python -m pip install xlrd
/usr/bin/python3: No module named pip

I tried this and this is the response. I guess I installed pip for python2.7 before I changed the alias

Comment: Try `pip3 --version` to see if that exists, and whether it exists for Python 3.6 or Python 3.7.

Comment: Okay, I managed to fix the import error. and xlrd seems to be correctly installed. However the traceback errors still occur when running my python script.

Comment: @hackerNuB Can you confirm if the version installed is >= 0.9.0.

Comment: @Manumathew "Installing collected packages: xlrd
Successfully installed xlrd-1.2.0"

Comment: How did you install xlrd? When importing on the Python prompt (for the Python version you're running), does xlrd indeed load correctly?